# Please explain this C++ syntax which seems to be incomplete or lacks assignment?

Tags: c++, syntax, operators, overloading

```
reply_form::reply_form()
{
    using cppcms::locale::translate;
    author.message(translate("Author"));
    comment.message(translate("Comment"));
    send.value(translate("Send"));
    *this + author + comment + send;
    author.limits(1,64);
    comment.limits(1,256);
}
```

In the given constructor definition, someone please explain what this syntax means or its intended use and benefits:

```
*this + author + comment + send;
```

To me, it appears as if a concatenation/addition which is done without it being assigned to anything, and thats really confusing me as I am not able to understand its purpose.

I have made good searches on web with the problem, but probably, I am not using the right term to search for it as I do not know what exactly this type of syntax is termed as.

I feel as if its the part of latest C++1x features, but not sure, so not able to find the right book for it. Finally chose stackoverflow for rescue :-)

EDIT:

the Most relevant I could provide is its declaration in header file, which is:

```
struct reply_form : public cppcms::form {
    cppcms::widgets::text author;
    cppcms::widgets::textarea comment;
    cppcms::widgets::submit send;
    reply_form();
};
```

EDIT2:Revision2 (corrected again after checking comments)

Ok, I was able to traceback the operator+ thing, and found out the way it was overloaded:

```
    inline form &operator + (form &f)
    {
        add(f);
        return *this;
    }
```

So this was the case of operator overloading. Thanks for your answer. I have been recently migrated to C++ and had found some strange things as I had posted in this thread:
[Explain blank class functions in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6928913/explain-blank-class-functions-in-c) which appeared to me as multifunction list with blank body,  but later I understood it as a syntax and a way of declaring a variable or calling the base class constructor.

Thanks for your answers, it were really helpful and very quick!

Comment: Well, how is `reply_form::operator+ (...)` defined, what overloads it has, and what it does? Only you can answer this, you have the code...

Comment: The overload in Edit 2 has nothing to do with the line you are wondering about. `a + b` and `a++` are different operators.

Comment: "but later I understood it as a syntax and a way of declaring a variable or calling the base class constructor" No. It's a way of initialising data members, or of _explicitly_ invoking the base constructor (as opposed to it being _implicitly_ invoked with no arguments).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most likely is a fluent operator overwritten to add fields to a `reply_form`. Eg.

```
reply_form& reply_form::operator+ (const field& value)
{
    this->add_field (value);
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: PS. This would be an appalling design.

Comment: Agreed. This why all language designers shunned operator overloading after they realized what it can lead to... 'What do you mean `operator ->()` calls FireMissile()?`

Comment: :) It can still be very powerful, effective and _intuitive_. It just needs using properly, like everything else.

Comment: Just run into a good example the other day: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/program_options/tutorial.html#id2190970

Comment: nobody in his sane mind writes a mutating `operator+`, it's what `operator+=` is for.

Comment: @Remus: That has nothing to do with operator overloading. It's just bad design... 'What do you mean DrawCicle() calls FireMissile()?'

Answer (score 9):

Since we don't know what `reply_form` is, this question cannot be answered in completion. Your question is more about the program than about C++.

The line `*this + author + comment + send;` *can* have side-effects if `reply_form::operator+` has side-effects.

Conventionally, though, it would not (because it doesn't make intuitive sense, as you've discovered). So, either this is a fault in the class's design, or the line should read something like `*this += author + comment + send;`.

Answer (score 3):

Since in C++, almost all operators can be overloaded, it could mean anything. In reality, the line in question is a sequence of nested calls to the function `operator+`:

```
operator+(operator+(operator+(*this, author), comment), send);
```

You need to look at how the `reply_form` class has overloaded `operator+`.

Answer (score 3):

Small thing:

This code

```
reply_form::reply_form()
{
    using cppcms::locale::translate;
    author.message(translate("Author"));
    comment.message(translate("Comment"));
    send.value(translate("Send"));
    *this + author + comment + send;
    author.limits(1,64);
    comment.limits(1,256);
}
```

Can and should be written as:

```
reply_form::reply_form()
{
    using cppcms::locale::translate;

    author.message(translate("Author"));
    author.limits(1,64);

    comment.message(translate("Comment"));
    comment.limits(1,256);

    send.value(translate("Send"));

    add(author);
    add(comment);
    add(send);

}
```

And actually new code should use this more verbose but clear API.

The `operator+` is kept for backward compatibility and is used
in some not-up-to-date examples.

Comment: Ohh, thanks for clarification artyom, it appears quite simple now! :)

Answer (score 0):

For example,

```
reply_form& operator+(reply_form& lValue,const reply_form& rValue);
```

would work correct in this case.